# Text align in CSS does not seem to function on VSCODE

Tags: html, css

I am making a survey and I need to centre the h1 in the centre of the page. It seems to work on Codepen.io but doesn't seem to work on VS-CODE.
This is my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Milkshake Survey 2020</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="MS">Milkshake Survey</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
#MS {
  text-align:center;
}
```

It seems to have worked on code.io
link: https://codepen.io/abhirajsb/pen/xxVgGwj

But on VSCODE it does not seem to work and the title is always on the left.
I need to know what mistakes i am making. (i am a beginner)

Comment: What do you mean 'on VSCODE'? In the IDE?

Comment: Is your cache cleared? If you inspect the element in the browser, does it have the css property?

Comment: I think another style is interfering with this. This `h1` should be centered.

Comment: you don't include a `link` tag for the CSS. Codepen does this for you behind the scene.

Comment: thank you @rioV8  it worked. I have so much to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I had to include a link in my HTML file to connect the HTML page to the css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="survey.css">
```

Thank you to @rioV8 for the quick response and others for the contribution.